# Access files using file url

Tags: linux, file, unix

I am running an apache web server on CentOS with few files placed under /var/www/html/ directory. I wanted to try to access those files using the file URL from my local machine. For example: file:///192.168.1.1/var/www/html/file1.txt.

However when I try to access over file protocol, I get "Page Not Found". The same works when access it over http. What could be wrong here?

```
~]# ssh root@192.168.1.1
root@192.168.1.1's password:
Last login: Mon Oct 26 01:44:36 2015 from 192.168.1.100

~]# cd /var/www/html/
html]# ls
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

[File uri scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) have **nothing** to do with http service. On windows, this is implemented with active directory; on unix system, I think this is only for local file system direct access.

Comment: thanks.. the file url scheme is only for local in case of unix.. and that could be the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

If /var/www/html/ is your HTML root, you Need to Access the files through file:///192.168.1.1/file1.txt.

Because if you set /var/www/html/ as your root in Apache config, you are not allowed to see the parent directories on the web.

Comment: Yes, /var/www/html is the DocumentRoot.. However it still doesn't work with file:///192.168.1.1/file.txt

Comment: You should also be able to acces .txt files with http:// did you try that? otherwise i assume you have a problem with the Apache config.

Comment: yes, i am able to access it through http protocol.. In this case, i wanted to try using file which is not working. Any help please?